# Configuring ASP.NET Core razor page filter using model.Filters.Add<TFilterType>()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I can setup an ASP.NET Core razor page filter in startup that has dependency injection just fine using `<<TType>>()` rather than `new Type()`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<Filters.AdminPageFilter>();
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

This works fine, but would like to apply this to a directory doing something like:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddFolderApplicationModelConvention(
        "/Admin",
        model => model.Filters.Add<Filters.AdminPageFilter>()
        );
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Compilation complains:

> Error  CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configureSource' of 'ConfigurationExtensions.Add(IConfigurationBuilder, Action)'    Startup.cs  71  Active

Is there a way to Just specify the type via `model.Filters.Add<Filters.AdminPageFilter>()` and not create an new Instance via `model.Filters.Add(new Filters.AdminPageFilter())`?

Answer (score 1):

[TypeFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.typefilterattribute) can help with this. It operates as a filter factory that can generate your filter using dependency injection. It implements `IFilterMetadata`, so it can be added to `model.Filters` in the place of your AdminPageFilter.

Here's an extension method that will give you the same `.Add<FilterType>` functionality:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public static void Add<TFilterType>(this ICollection<IFilterMetadata> filters) where TFilterType : IFilterMetadata {
    var typeFilterAttribute = new TypeFilterAttribute(typeof(TFilterType));
    filters.Add(typeFilterAttribute);
}
```